# Do simple commands in bash run in subshells, since a single command can constitute a pipeline?

Tags: bash

The Bash Reference Manual state:

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands

Thus, wouldn't any command therefore be qualified as a pipeline? This doesn't seem to be a purely semantic issue since the manual also states:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell

So this would mean something as simple as `echo foo` would, in fact, run in a subshell?

Comment: `echo 'Yes' | echo $(</dev/stdin)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual is not a *formal specification*. The formal specification which bash complies with (implements a large superset of) is [the POSIX shell command language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). That specification states the rule more clearly, [in section 2.12](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12), with formatting added for emphasis:

> Additionally, each command **of a multi-command pipeline** is in a subshell environment[...]

Thus, a simple single-command pipeline (1) is in fact a pipeline; but (2) does not invoke subshells.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a single command is also a pipeline. To verify this, you run any commamd, say `echo foo` and then print the `PIPESTATUS` variable by using the below command.

```
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Comment: I don't believe the OP is asking about the "subshell level", but about whether a `fork()` takes place. `set -x` can indeed be used to verify that, but you'd want to do something like `PS4=':$BASHPID+'` first; if the BASHPID is identical to the parent process's, then there was no fork for that line.

Answer (score 0):

Working backward, your last statement is correct that running a single command on a bash prompt causes a fork. So in that sense a single command is treated as a pipeline.

However `bash -c 'echo hello'` does not cause an extra fork.

The single command is treated as a special case, compared to a "proper" pipeline such as `bash -c 'echo hello|wc'`, which creates 2 forks, 1 each to handle `echo` and `wc`, while the original process waits for those children to complete.

Though I have to say that something as simple as `echo` is in fact an internal command, which means it is entirely implemented within the bash executable, and a child program execution never takes place.

Comment: As `echo hello | wc` still forks off a subshell to run the `echo hello` in, so I'm not sure the builtin-vs-external distinction is pertinent here. I don't believe the OP was asking about presence or absence of a pre-`exec()` fork at all, vs the fork to create a subshell for a pipeline component.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy but is "a subshell" simply the `fork` or is it more substantial than that? To be fair there isn't much more to it, and the phrase "subshell" is over-egging the bacon a little.